# Distinguishing attack on CBC-MAC

Tags: cbc-mac, distinguisher

I want to ask about **distinguishing attack on CBC MAC**, as in the paper published by Ketting Jia, Xiaoyun Wang, Zheng Yuan, and Guangwu Xu: [***Distinguishing Attack and Second-Preimage Attack on the CBC-like MACs.***](http://eprint.iacr.org/2008/542)

In that paper it is said that "**if there is a collision in the structure, the MAC function is random function. Otherwise it is a CBC MAC.**"

What is the meaning of that statement?

As I know, random function does not have collision, but in that statement it is said that if there is a collision, it is random function.

Comment: Random functions have collisions, random permutations (block ciphers) don't. See [Is it possible to distinguish a securely-encrypted ciphertext from random noise?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-a-securely-encrypted-ciphertext-from-random-noise/1651#1651) I'd guess the paper describes a variant of that, but I didn't look at it.

Answer (score 5):

The quoted sentences means: if there is a collision among the MACs of the $2^{(n+1)/2}$ messages submitted, the attacker playing the distinguishing game announces that the oracle is a random function; else announces that the oracle is [CBC-MAC](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-44750-4_1.pdf).

This works because the messages submitted differ only in their first block, thus will never collide under CBC-MAC, when they collide with odds $0.632\dots$ (by the birthday "paradox") for a random function. The attacker employing the strategy outlined in a game where the objective is distinguishing between an oracle implementing a random function, and an (equally likely) oracle implementing CBC-MAC with a fixed random key, will have an advantage compared to announcing a result at random.

Update: to prove that there are never collisions with CBC-MAC, assume that there is such collision between two messages identical in all but the first block; use that a block cipher with a fixed key is a permutation over the set $\{0,1\}^n$; and conclude that the first block must be identical in the two messages.

So far, this is purely a distinguisher, without much practical applications. However the paper goes on to explain another attack, which I'll illustrate in a simplified version below.

---

Assume [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC) using messages of three blocks, a block cipher of $n$ bits, and $n$-bit output. The attacker obtains the MAC of $2^{(n+1)/2}$ messages $M_j=j||j||0$ where the first two blocks are $j$ and the third block all-zero. Odds that a collision on the MAC occurs is about $0.632\dots$ (both for a random function and CBC-MAC). If that happens for messages $M_a$ and $M_b$, the adversary submits $M'_a=a||a||1$ and $M'_b=b||b||1$. If the MAC is CBC-MAC, there will with certainty be a MAC collision between $M'_a$ and $M'_b$, whereas odds of such a collision would be $2^{-n}$ if the MAC was a random function.

This allows computing a second preimage of a message with any desired third block, after little more than $2^{n/2}$ queries.

This attack is known as a *birthday forgery*. It is briefly discussed in ISO/IEC 9797-1, which standardizes CBC-MAC, as early as in the 1999 edition, with attribution to Bart Preneel and Paul C. van Oorschot: [*MDx-MAC and Building Fast MACs from Hash Functions*](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44750-4_1.pdf), published in the proceedings of Crypto 1995.

For in-depth coverage of similar attacks on CBC-MAC, see the work of Antoine Joux, Guillaume Poupard, and Jacques Stern: [*New attacks against standardized MACs*](http://www.iacr.org/archive/fse2003/28870178/28870178.pdf), published in the [proceedings of FSE 2003](http://www.iacr.org/archive/fse2003/fse2003.html); or/and Karl Brincat and Chris J. Mitchell: *[New CBC-MAC forgery attacks](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-47719-5_2)* (preliminary zipped version [here](http://www.chrismitchell.net/ncmfa.zip)), published in the proceedings of ACISP 2001.