# Distinguishing Attack on CBC-MACs

Tags: cbc-mac, distinguisher

I want to ask [again](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12781/555) about distinguishing attack on CBC MAC, based on the paper published by Ketting Jia, Xiaoyun Wang, Zheng Yuan, and Guangwu Xu: [*Distinguishing Attack and Second-Preimage Attack on the CBC-like MACs*](http://eprint.iacr.org/2008/542).

That paper says: "The adversary makes $2^{(n+1)/2}$ queries with $m$-block messages that have the same last $m−1$ blocks."

What I want to ask is why the authors choose $2^{(n+1)/2}$?

As we know, block cipher's input width is usually even, so if we operated it with $2^{(n+1)/2}$ the result will not be an integer, but fractional.

Comment: For why odds of collision are better than 50% after $2^{(n+1)/2}$ queries but not $2^{n/2}$, study the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), focusing on the case of a large set. Note: Here, $2^{(n+1)/2}$ is written `$2^{(n+1)/2}$`

Answer (score 2):

Why approximately $2^{(n+1)/2}$ queries?  Because it makes the attack work.

As far as your final comment, it sounds like you are confusing $(n+1)/2$ with $2^{(n+1)/2}$.  If we use AES, then $n=128$, so $(n+1)/2=64.5$.  However, $2^{64.5}$ is a very large number.  The exact number of queries is not important as long as it is approximately $2^{64.5}$, and it is easy to choose an integer near that number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I mean why the authors choose $2^{(n+1)/2}$ ?
Why the authors not choose $2^{n/2}$ ? Is it based in birthday paradox or what?

Comment: @user11291, read fgrieu's earlier comment, and do some learning on your own about the birthday paradox.